# Overloading Comparison Operators in c++

Tags: c++, this, overloading, operator-keyword

How do I overload my operator such that I can compare two vertex pointers?

```
class graph
{
private:
class vertex;
class edge;

class vertex
{
public:
    int index;
    int estDistanceToGoal;
    int traveledDis;
    string location;
```

Here is an example of when I overload the > operator.
The problem is this method on triggers when I have a vertex object being compared with a vertex pointer.

```
    bool operator> (vertex* v)
    {
                    cout<<"we did this"<<endl;
        return (this->weight > v->weight);
    }
```

Here is an example I used to test it. It would only print "we did this" if I had an vertex object and a vertex pointer being compared. So how do I make it so I compare the two vertex pointers? Can you deference "this"?

```
    void test()
{
    vertex*a = new vertex("wj",5);
    vertex*v = new vertex("something",2);

    if(a == v)
    {
        cout<<"what"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"k"<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should compare the vertexes themselves, i.e. `if (*a < *v)`, and define the comparison object to take a vertex argument.

Comment: You wouldn't expect to be able to compare two `int` values by comparing the pointers to them, why would you do it differently with `vertex`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, thankfully. All of the comparison operators already have a well established behavior for pointers of any type. And you can't overload operators unless at least one of the parameters is a user defined type.

Comment: so then what do you suggest I do if I need to compare two vertex pointers? Do all my data structures have to be vertex objects instead?

Comment: @user2782774: That's an option, and one which should generally be preferred. But even if you have pointers, you can always dereference them at the point of comparison.

Comment: @user2782774 Are you sure comparing pointers is what you need? It doesn't seem like it (a regular graph). You can, as Benjamin said, take pointers and then just dereference them to do the comparison.

Comment: yes but there are instances where I need them to be pointers. Such as the the vertex holding a predecessor vertex pointer. Is there a way to I guess reference? Such as *pointer deferences it. Is there a way to change an object to a pointer?

Comment: Put an `&` in front of it, but I don't see how that helps you. What is stopping you from overloading the operator for vertex objects, and simply dereferencing your pointers in order to pass them to the operator?

Comment: I guess having all my data structures as vertex pointers. Trying to do it this way now.